# Submit doesn't do HTTP Post but does http get/request instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit an update to a team in my database (one single table).  However, upon clicking Submit or Save to update the team, it keeps calling the first Edit() that responsible for HTTP Request and not the Edit() function in the controller that responsible for HTTP Post.

Any idea why it behaves this way? could it be I'm using a partial page and my master page is the _Layout.cshtml.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Team",FormMethod.Post))  {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Team</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Model:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Team team = db.Teams.Find(id);
        if (team == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(team);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Team/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Team team)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(team);
    }
```

Result including the URL after my submit.

[image]

Bundles:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Styles/layout.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
```

Filter:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the end form call and forgot to copy it or is that missing? Also what do you get when you view source?

Comment: would you mind to elaborate more on your questions? i'm quite new to .net MVC so I'm not quite following what you mean.

Comment: ON your browser you can look at the source of the page if its correct it should look something like this.
<form action="/Action" method="post">    
    <fieldset>
        Select a file <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

Comment: @AlfredoAlvarez I would think he would be more confused about the question regarding the end form call. Not trying to put words in his mouth, but that is what I assume. And as far as that goes he's using the @ using directive which will automatically add the closing form tag at the ending bracket "}".

Comment: @Fylix I just ran the code you provided above and was redirected to the Index page as expected. Also, I looked at the headers and can see that it is indeed being sent as a POST. So at this point I would wager that the above code is correct and that the problem lies somewhere else. It could be something in a route or filter. Could you add those files to your question? You can find them in the App_Start directory under your project. ProjectName->App_Start.

Comment: @Alfredo user was right, i was just confuse about the end form. Thanks user, let me look again carefully at my solution and start stripping down the element to troubleshoot this.  I'll keep you posted, I don't want to mislead you unless I reduce this issue down to its simplest components.

Comment: I have a <form></form> in my _Layout.cshtml.  My MVC view above is a partial page which I use the _Layout.cshtml as a layout page.  Will that be a problem?  I'm coming from the apsx engine so I have this master page  mentality entrenched in me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found my issue:

i have a layout page _Layout.cshml and I have a form tag in that page where i put my view in there as a partial page.  upon removing the form out, the mvc posts properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you probably shouldn't put form tags in your layouts.. confusion like this is one reason...